# Can I say that a book is "well-guided"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I need to offer some advice about how a friend of mine can learn a new language effectively. Does the following sound correct?

> Make sure you choose a ***well-guided*** course book with clear and understandable explanations.

Comment: You can if someone is throwing it accurately.

Answer (score 3):

No, this doesn't make sense.

Literally it means that "something guides the book well".  But what you probably mean is "a book that guides the reader well"

You can then look to see if this is an idiom (by typing "well guided book" into your favourite search engine.  On my google this finds this question and a barber shop in "WellGuided Hair" in Torquay, England.

You might say "well-written book" or you could omit this adjective completely.

(I'm not sure about "course book" since a course book is a set book for a course, and the choice of course book is made by the teacher, not the learner.  Anyway it would be more helpful to recommend a particular book, since the advice here is probably something she already knew.)